# TextView contrast on a lighter background image in Android

Tags: android

[image]

I have this textview which is white in color and I am putting on top of an image with lighter background. The problem is that the text "My App" is barely visible. Is it the contrast or what do I have to change on textview to stand the bright white color out? If the background color of image is dark then the white color stand out but in this case it almost blends.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/skyline"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_75dp"
        android:text="My App"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Don't use pure white.  An off white would have better contrast.

Comment: what is the question here? yes some colors are more visible on a lighter background than others , are you asking what color to use or how to change text color? to change color use android:textColor="#000000" inside TextView

Answer (score 0):

Add a translucent background to your TextView

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_75dp"
    android:text="My App"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#30000000"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
```

Edit: based on your comment, look at the [Palette](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) library.

Comment: Adding this did result in standing out the white color however now there is a grey box in the background of text "My App". If I make the translucent as transparent then I am back to square one. Other solution which I don't want to use is to create an image with text "My App"  but I think there should be a solution.

Comment: Then you should consider using the Palette library and determine the colours of your image at run time and pick a contrasting one from the set given by the library.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your situation, I'll try to tackle the issue by handling both image and text, since we might have a bright background with a white text or vice Versa.

First, we'll make sure our image background is dark enough to let our white textView visible clearly, I recommend to apply a light overlay upon the imageview (Framelayout with top image) or even use the `alpha` attribute.

Now that our image is arranged, we should do the same for the textview but this time using shadows, like the following

```
android:shadowColor="#000000#"
android:shadowDx="0"
android:shadowDy="2"
android:shadowRadius="20"
```

Change the above values according to your needs.

Hope that answers your question.